# How do I go back to the main menu from a sub menu using JOptionPane when the user clicks cancel?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I'm making a method wherein it has several choices and each of those choices , once selected, need to have the "cancel" button go back to the main menu.

Main Menu:

```
 public static void start(){
   String[] choices = {"1. Routines for Triangles","2. Routines for Temperatures","3. Routines for Geometric Figures","4. String Manipulations",
                                            "5. Miscellaneous Simple Games.","6. Quit"};
   String menu = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"choose","Main menu",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,choices,choices[0])
       while (menu != null){
           switch (menu){
               case "1. Routines for Triangles":
                   triangleRoutines(); //one sub menu
                   break;
               case "2. Routines for Temperatures":
                   break;
               case "3. Routines for Geometric Figures":
                   break;
               case "4. String Manipulations":
                   break;
               case "5. Miscellaneous Simple Games.":
                   break;
               case "6. Quit":
                   break;

           }
       }

   }
```

A sub menu:

```
private static void triangleRoutines(){

   String[] stringArray = {"Determine the Type of Triangle", "Determine a Valid Triangle", "Determine the Area of the Sides of a Triangle", "Determine a Pythagorean Triple",
                            };
       String reply = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose what you want to do today", "Triangle Processes", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
               null, stringArray, stringArray[0]);

           switch (reply){
               case "Determine the Type of Triangle":
                   break;
               case "Determine a Valid Triangle":
                   break;
               case "Determine the Area of the Sides of a Triangle":
                   break;
               case "Determine a Pythagorean Triple":
                   break;
           }
 }
```

Comment: The codes not done yet because I need to figure out my cancel button first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a **JOptionPane.showInputDialog()** dialog is ***Canceled*** or ***Closed*** without a selection being made then a **null** is returned. you need to handle this null and act upon it accordingly but you will need to decide what you want to do when it does happen. Close the application, re-display the Main Menu dialog and force the Quit menu option to be selected, etc.

To always keep your *Main Menu* available place it within the **while** loop, for example:

```
String[] choices = {"1. Routines for Triangles", "2. Routines for Temperatures", 
                    "3. Routines for Geometric Figures", "4. String Manipulations",
                    "5. Miscellaneous Simple Games.", "6. Quit"};

String menu = "";
while (!menu.equals("6. Quit")) {
    menu = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "<html>Choose A Menu Item:<br><br></html>", "Main Menu", 
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, choices, choices[0]);
    if (menu == null) {
        //continue; //uncomment and delete line below to force menu item 6 to be selected to quit Main Menu.
        break; //Quit the Main Menu
    }

    switch (menu) {
        case "1. Routines for Triangles":
            triangleRoutines();  //one sub menu
            break;
        case "2. Routines for Temperatures":
            break;
        case "3. Routines for Geometric Figures":
            break;
        case "4. String Manipulations":
            break;
        case "5. Miscellaneous Simple Games.":
            break;
        case "6. Quit":
            // This case is not really required unless you want to
            // do some cleanup of sorts before quiting. 
            break;
        }
    }
```

Utilize the same technique for your methods which contain sub-menus but add a menu option to: `Return To Main Menu` and perhaps one more additional option to: `Quit Application` if desired.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to implement the [`Command` design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

However, if the point is that the `triangleRoutines` needs to return to the previous menu, then given the overall current approach, I think making a modification on where the menu is presented would work. I'm not positive that is the OP's question, but I believe so.

See the comments in the example code for additional details.

Not tested, but something like:

```
private static void triangleRoutines() {
  ...

  // if the program is done, can return null

  // if cancel, then return anything but null
  return "";
}
```

Then

```
do {
  // get the menu from the top level
  String menu = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"choose","Main menu",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,choices,choices[0])
   switch (menu){
       case "1. Routines for Triangles":
           // if cancel, then will return empty string, and then
           //  re-present the main menu 
           triangleRoutines(); //one sub menu
           break;

       ...

       case "6. Quit":
           menu = null;
           break;
   } //switch
} while (menu != null);
```

Thus, in the `triangleRoutines()` one can "cancel" and it will return an empty `String`, which is not null, so it will present the top level menu again. If one wants to exit from the submenu `triangleRoutines()` then return null, and the program will exit.

Again, I might have misunderstood the specific question.